# Windows 7 Drivers for Dell Inspiron 1420

Tags: windows-7, drivers, download, 32-bit, dell-inspiron

I've installed Windows 7 onto my Dell Inspiron 1420 (32-Bit). I don't have an internet connection at home, so I want to download drivers into my flash drive. I searched Dell website for drivers but  didn't find anything exclusively for Windows 7. Can anyone direct me to the archive/repository where I could find drivers which suit my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select *Windows Vista 32-bit* as your operating system on your laptop's official [driver page](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&osl=EN&catid=-1&impid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1420&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en). These drivers should do fine with Windows 7 as well.

Comment: while downloading drivers how can i asses which driver is good for a Dell inspiron n5050 laptop.Is there anything like that or i blindly download the complete driver set and simply install all of them.